# Writing getters and setters in Typescript(Ionic2)

Tags: typescript

In my ionic2 application, I need to store user information such that it is available even after user closes and re-opens the app. Hence I am using SqlStorage Service for this.

However the code is pretty lengthy and ugly:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Storage, SqlStorage} from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class Profile {
  private _storage: any;

  constructor(private _api: ApiEndpoint, private _uploadService: UploadService) {
    this._storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
  }

  get firstname(): string {
    return this._storage.get('firstname');
  }

  set firstname(value: string) {
     this._storage.set('firstname', value);
  }

  get lastname(): string {
    return this._storage.get('lastname');
  }

  set lastname(value: string) {
    this._storage.set('lastname', value);
  }

  get username(): string {
    return this._storage.get('username');
  }

  set username(value: string) {
    this._storage.set('username', value);
  }

 ....
 ....
 .... and so on for every field
```

My Question is, is there a better way to write this code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the getters and setters at runtime using a decorator.  As far as the type system is concerned, a property with getters and setters and an ordinary property are the same.  Therefore, declaring them at runtime won't violate the type-system.

Here's an example in the [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%09import%20%7B%20Injectable%20%7D%20from%20'%40angular%2Fcore'%3B%0A%09import%20%7BStorage%2C%20SqlStorage%7D%20from%20'ionic-angular'%3B%0A%09%0A%09function%20Storage(target%2C%20propName%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%09%09Object.defineProperty(target%2C%20propName%2C%20%7B%0A%09%09%09configurable%3A%20true%2C%0A%09%09%09get%3A%20function()%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09return%20this._storage.get(propName)%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%2C%0A%09%09%09set%3A%20function(v)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09return%20this._storage.set(propName%2C%20v)%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09%40Injectable()%0A%09export%20class%20Profile%20%7B%0A%09%09private%20_storage%3A%20any%3B%0A%09%09%0A%09%09constructor(private%20_api%3A%20ApiEndpoint%2C%20private%20_uploadService%3A%20UploadService)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this._storage%20%3D%20new%20Storage(SqlStorage)%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%0A%09%09%40Storage%0A%09%09firstname%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%09%40Storage%0A%09%09lastname%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%09%40Storage%0A%09%09username%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%7D)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Storage, SqlStorage} from 'ionic-angular';

function Storage(target, propName: string) {
    Object.defineProperty(target, propName, {
        configurable: true,
        get: function() {
            return this._storage.get(propName);
        },
        set: function(v) {
            return this._storage.set(propName, v);
        }
    });
}

@Injectable()
export class Profile {
    private _storage: any;

    constructor(private _api: ApiEndpoint, private _uploadService: UploadService) {
        this._storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
    }

    @Storage
    firstname: string;
    @Storage
    lastname: string;
    @Storage
    username: string;
}
```